# NSPredicate with three entities

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate, fetch

I have 3 entities in model graph (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2669769/model.png):

Company <—>> Person <<—> Role

I want to retrieve from a selected Company a list of Employees with their roles, but my predicate appears incomplete. Any suggestion?

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@“Person” inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self in %@",[selectedCompany employee]];
[request setEntity:entity];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",[fetchedObjects valueForKey:@“firstName”]); // OK
NSLog(@"%@",[fetchedObjects valueForKey:@“inRole.name”]); // NULL!!!
```

Comment: Firstly, in your predicate, IN specifies that the right hand argument is an array; does [selectedCompany employee] return an array?
Secondly, dictionary result type fetches cannot return relationships that are to-many; is "inRole" a to-many relationship?

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I removed request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType; and now the relationship is on.

Comment: If you don't answer the question as an answer the system leaves it open forever AND you don't get credit.

Comment: @bioglp I have written out my answer below, if it was the solution to your issue, please accept it as the correct answer by selecting the check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSDictionaryResultType` on your fetch request does not allow for to-many relationships. This is why `inRole.name` is not populated in your dictionary.